# Accessing UserControls in a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

The View : I have UserControl, which has a TextBox and a Label. When the "Enter" key is down, I want the Label to be updated with the value form the text box. For the sake of this example, I created a CarUserControl. I will be hosting a list of these in an ItemsControl in the MainWindow.

The Model : I have class Car, which will be the model.

The ViewModel : I do not have a ViewModel for the CarUserControl and the Car. I  have one for the MainWindow instead - lets call this the MainViewModel.

I can get the commands propogated from the individual usercontrols to the MainViewModel, but I'm unsure about getting the values from the textboxes in the MainViewModel?

Here are some of the assumptions I'm making from what I`ve read online about MVVM (there are ofcourse some sources which say the assumptions are wrong).

1] Usercontrols should not have a ViewModel.

2] Usercontrols should only expose dependency properties, and not public properties with INotifyChanged or events.

So, the question is, how do I update the label, and access the TextBox value in the MainViewModel.

Here is the test code :

-----CarUserControl.xaml----

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMVVM.CarUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMVVM"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="thisUC">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0">--</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Background="#FFE8D3D3" BorderThickness="0">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" 
                                Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand, ElementName=thisUC}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

-----CarUserControl.cs-----

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestMVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CarUserControl.xaml
    /// The Usercontrol
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CarUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private static readonly DependencyProperty StrValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StrValue", typeof(float), typeof(CarUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        private static readonly DependencyProperty KeyDownCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyDownCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CarUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null)); //Enter key down in the text box

        public CarUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string StrValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(StrValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrValueProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// "Enter" key down
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand KeyDownCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(KeyDownCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(KeyDownCommandProperty, value); }
        }


    }
}
```

//---The Model--Car.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestMVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A simple model
    /// </summary>
    class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Car(string name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private string name;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

-----Main View Model---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestMVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Main View Model
    /// </summary>
    class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main view model
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //Create some test data
            cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
            cars.Add(new Car("Audi"));
            cars.Add(new Car("Toyota"));
            cars.Add(new Car("Subaru"));
            cars.Add(new Car("Volvo"));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private ObservableCollection<Car> cars; //List of tensioner spools
        private ICommand enterDownCommand;

        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
        {
            get { return cars; }
            set
            {
                cars = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cars");
            }
        }

        public ICommand EnterDownCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (enterDownCommand == null)
                {
                    enterDownCommand = new RelayMCommand<Car>(OnEnterDownCommand);
                }
                return enterDownCommand;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when "Enter" key is down. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        private void OnEnterDownCommand(Car obj)
        {
            //How do I get the text box value here?
            Console.Write(">>"+obj.Name);
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-----MainWindow---

```
  <Window x:Class="TestMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMVVM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Name ="MainVM"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Viewbox>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" Margin="5" Width="200">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:CarUserControl Margin="5"
                                                  KeyDownCommand="{Binding Path=DataContext.EnterDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

---Relay Command---

```
   using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestMVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Same as the Relay Command, except this handles an array of generic type <T>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type parameter</typeparam>
    public class RelayMCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        private Predicate<T> _canExecute;
        private Action<T> _execute;

        public RelayMCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        private void Execute(T parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        private bool CanExecute(T parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return parameter == null ? false : CanExecute((T)parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute((T)parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            var temp = Volatile.Read(ref CanExecuteChanged);
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UserControl` may inherit its `DataContext` from a parent window or the current item in an `ItemsControl`.

So if you bind your `ItemsControl` to an `IEnumerable<Car>`, each instance of the `CarUserControl` can bind directly to the `Name` property of the corresponding `Car` object:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" 
            Grid.Column="1" Background="#FFE8D3D3" BorderThickness="0">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" 
                    Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand, ElementName=thisUC}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

This is because the `UserControl` automatically inherits the `DataContext` from its parent element which is the corresponding `Car` object in the `ItemsControl` in this case.

Comment: Makes sense. But how do I get the KeyDown command to update the label in the UserControl with the value in the TextField?

Comment: You could bind the KeyDownCommand property of the UC to a command property of the Car object that sets the source property that the Label is bound to, to the value of the source property that the TextBox is bound to. So you should also bind the Label to a property of the Car object.

Comment: I`m a bit confused. So, do I have to set a property in the UserControl when the Enter key is pressed, and then expose it to the Label through binding? I thought the UserControl should not handle events. Maybe edits to the code can help me understand the concept. I would appreciate it. The TextBox is an active input, the user can change it at any point, and once the Enter key is pressed the Property bound to the label needs to be updated.

Comment: Not in the UC but in its DataContext, i.e. the Car class. This should have three properties, two string properties that you bind to the TextBox and the Label and one command property.

Comment: I think I have figured this out. I was a bit uncomfortable using Command property in the Car class, as Microsoft MVVM docs say the ViewModel is where the handling of the View Commands should take place. So, I didnot add a command property in the Car class. But, I did add another property in the Model class which is bound to the label. Then I call a method from the ViewModel class to update the Model class, just as MVVM framework suggests - or at least my understanding of it.

Comment: The Car class is practically a view model since it implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. This is a UI specific interface that shouldn't be implemented in a pure model class.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if it helped you to solve your issue.

Comment: Then how does a ViewModel know a property in the Model has changed? There are threads out there, some in support of using INotifyPropertyChanged in a Model. I'm the beginning stages, so it`ll be helpful to pick a direction now.

Comment: It doesn't unless the model tells it somehow, for example by raising an event. But the point is that a model is typically a service layer or a class that implements an interface that the view model class may get injected with. You typically bind to view model classes that implement property change notifications. If you put properties that you bind to in the Car class, you might as well put the command property in there as well.

Comment: The best approach I have found is to implement INCP in the model too. It`s not a pure MVVM approach like I had hoped for. Also, INCP is part of the System.ComponentModel and not a UI specific interface.